# How to find app based on package name?

Tags: applications, adb, malware

I've installed a malicious app that is posting ads over my notification bar, but can't find it. I know the java package name for it: `com.letang.game103.en` using the command: `adb shell dumpsys notification`.

As you see the name of the app is not obvious from the package name. I want to find which app it is, that uses this package name. I also want to report them to Android Market, after leaving a nice feedback for them there!

I've looked at different dumpsys commands:

```
adb shell dumpsys [something]
```

But so far wasn't able to get apps based on their package names.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way, without using any specialized tools is just to visit that app's page in the Play Store (website, not app).

All apps in the Play Store have their package name as part of their URL, so you can just take your package name and prefix it with `https://play.google.com/details?id=` to get

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin

where `com.stackexchange.marvin` is the package name which will take you to the page for Stack Exchange Android app.

Comment: Doesn’t help me finding the common name of "com.android.providers.telephony”.

Comment: @RobertSiemer `com.android.providers.telephony` is one of the core packages of Android, so it doesn't have or need to be on Play Store.

Comment: @Firelord, I didn’t complain that it is not on Play Store, I complained that the answer doesn’t work with my example!

Comment: @RobertSiemer this answer was written as the quickest and easiest way to identify non-built-in apps (as these are all that the question was asking about). If you want an easy way to identify built-in system apps, then I suggest you Ask that as a question. However it's fairly easy to remember that "com.android" indicates a built-in app, and to guess what "telephony" might be doing.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I quote: “How to find app based on package name?” and I continue quoting: “But so far wasn't able to get apps based on their package names. Is there any way to do this?” – I’m very well aware that the _background_ given in addition to the question limits the scope and the answer given here works for that scope. – You know what? I’ll upvote this. The answer is good, but it doesn’t completely answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

The question was asked back in 2012 but given that no Android version constraint is given I would like to suggest a solution, which as of now is helpful **for Android 5.0 and above**.

Install App Manager from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager/). Launch it, start searching your package name using the search/lens icon and your app would show up.

<sub>(Click image to see enlarged version)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This works even for apps which are not in play store.

Comment: Does not appear to work anymore, no apps are shown and searching repositories. S22.