# Get common name of an app given its package name

Tags: applications, adb, command-line

I'm interested in a way to go from the package name (e.g. `com.android.providers.telephony`) to its common name (*Phone*).

I'd like to know if there's ADB/shell command (from the phone), or any system/preinstalled app.

I know that a bunch of apps reveal both once you could pin the app in it. – In Android 4.x (tried with 4.2.2) you can even use the system app manager to confirm the package name once you found and selected the app via the common name.

Comment: Robert, if you're still looking for this, [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/16575) might be interesting for you. In short: CM-based ROMS with Kitkat or later ship with `aapt`; and if yours does not, you can install it yourself (root required, though). Having that, a one-liner calling to ADB does the job for you. Details "over there" ;)

Comment: For users who are willing to use an app based solution for this: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19865/96277

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't given up on Android apps yet, you can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). It lets you search either by app name or package name.

[image: TiBu]
<sup>Screenshot of *Titanium Backup* (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: is there a way to get it to show the package name for an app?