# How do I get list of all application packages together with their activity label from adb shell?

Tags: applications, command-line

Sometimes I have a trouble matching application's package name in `/data/data/` or `/data/app/*.apk` with the user-friendly activity label I see in GUI.

How do I list application packages together with their activities?

Expecting something like this:

```
$ adb shell list_apps
de.shandschuh.sparserss "Sparse rss"
org.vudroid "VuDroid"
jcpezzullo.statical "StatiCal"
tone.control "Tone Control"
...
```

Comment: Related: [Obtain package name AND common name of apps via ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90141/obtain-package-name-and-common-name-of-apps-via-adb) (no answer yet)

Comment: There is workaround using `aapt` on host: ```for i in /directory/with/downloaded/apk/files/*.apk; do printf '%s %s\n' "`aapt dump badging \"$i\" | grep application-label:`" "$i"; done```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/16575) on the question Andrew linked to, this is what should be in your `list_apps` script:

```
for app in $(ls /data/app/*.apk); do
    appname=$(aapt d badging $app | grep 'application: label' | sed -n \"s/.*label\='\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p\")
    pkgname=$(basename $app)
    echo ${pkgname} "${appname}"
done
```

Run this on your Android device.

- Requirements: Either a CM based ROM with Kitkat or higher (which seems to ship with the `aapt` binary) – or a rooted device where you can install `aapt` onto yourself ([find it here](http://android.izzysoft.de/downloads); tested with Android 4.1).
- Known issues: app name most likely gets truncated when it contains a single quote (see `sed` expression). Not having such one installed here I could not test that.
- Only lists user apps. Easy to fix by repeating the block for `/system/app` ;)

Comment: On Samsung Galaxy S 5, `ls /data` yields `opendir failed, Permission denied`.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon requirements not met, see first bullet-point: you need to be root for that.

Comment: fully valid point yet unexpected. [Firelord's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/42369) mentions non-root but mentions entering `/data` also.  Yet I remember having used an app that did this without root access. My guess is, there is probably a way to fulfill OP's question on a non-rooted device, perhaps just `aapt` in another temp location.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon you've missed one thing possibly: `ls /data` requires root, `ls /data/app` might not. I'm not sure about the permissions on that folder, but I wouldn't wonder if it's readable *and executable* to each app. Have you checked that? While without root you cannot *list the contents* of `/data`, you can `cd` into it, and also into `/data/app`. You just cannot list the contents of `/data` itself. But without access to tha `.apk` file it doesn't help to place `aapt` in another location either; the information required is stored in the `.apk` files.

Comment: thanks. Yes and no. You're right in that I can cd into `/data` and `/data/app`. But `ls` still fails in both locations, making the whole operation impractical. I expect the app did it via some API which has necessary access.

Comment: There might be a way to query those details via the package manager (`pm`) - which is what I e.g. use for many details in my little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar). But I never checked "activity labels" that way, so I cannot tell for sure (and I'm currently not at my desk so I cannot really verify). What I do with Adebar is, via `adb`, parsing the `packages.xml` which `pm` uses/maintains. you can check what can be found there, @StéphaneGourichon