# How do I get Application name from APK file?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, apk, system-info

When we click on apk file on android phone (assuming allowed installation from unknown sources), Application name appears.

Example screen-shot for `jackpal.androidterm-1.apk`:

[image: screen-shot]

Now, If I want to get this Application Name "Terminal Emulator" from apk file (`jackpal.androidterm-1.apk`) without installation prompt, then How do I do that?

So, My question is **How do I get Application name from an `.apk` file?**

As you know (from screen-shot) I use terminal, also I've installed busybox. So, Is there any command (like: `foo /path/to/.apk`) with the help of which I can get application name?

If I've to use application to do that, then I recommend to suggest [FLOSS type](https://f-droid.org/) application.

Note:- This is not about getting package name but application name. Also I am not talking about application that is already installed.

Comment: Related: [Obtain package name AND common name of apps via ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/90141/16575)

Comment: View apk manifest on PC : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=14523375#post14523375 .  Uses aapt from your SDK installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Works only on Cyanogenmod or forks that base on CM:**

<sup>`aapt` may not be present on your device. It's suspected that this binary is part of CyanogenMod (and its forks). Confirmed to be present on my S3 running Resurrection Remix (CM12.1), Izzy's Milestone² running CM11 and the LG P880 running CM11 as well.</sup>

You can use `aapt` (*Android Asset Packaging Tool*) to dump the data to your terminal.

Command:

```
aapt d badging <path to apk>

call aapt
     [d]ump the data
       print the badging (label and icon) of
               <the apk>
```

Your output will contain many lines beginning with `application-label`; those are localized labels so the one you are looking for is plain `application-label:`.
Use `grep` to filter your output and you will end up with this command:

```
aapt d badging <path to apk> | grep "application-label:"
```

This gives you the localized application label for a given *apk*.

### **Update: Thanks to Izzy for providing `aapt` for all devices running Android 4.1+:**

[Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) put together an archive containing the `aapt` binary for ARM devices (nearly all phones and tablets use ARM CPUs).
Get it from his website: http://android.izzysoft.de/downloads.

*Note:* the command to get the actual application label is slightly different, you need to use `awk` to isolate the application label from the rest of the output:

```
aapt d badging <path to apk> | grep "application: label" |awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: currectly command `aapt` not found. how to install *Android Asset Packaging Tool*?

Comment: @Pandya [some apps seem to include it](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2401179). Unfortunately, that's all I could find so far.

Comment: @Izzy those are IDEs, that are mentioned. They need to include `aapt` to be able to pack *apks*. I just checked my S3's 4.4.4 stock image, but I haven't found `aapt` in it. Seems like it only comes with the *development* version of Android.

Comment: So that confirms my suspicion it might be a CM specific thing (one more edit to your answer?). And yes, I'm aware those are IDEs – otherwise, what for should they include `aapt`? ;) But if one can get hold of the `.apk`, (s)he may extract the `aapt` binary plus the required lib(s) from it (`aapt` at least requires `libpng`).

Comment: Thanks! And yuck, I forgot the upvote (done now) – and we have to cleanup comments again ;) Btw: description for this `aapt` also [in my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/16575).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for providing [aapt](http://android.izzysoft.de/downloads.php?file=aapt-0.2.0.tar.gz)