# App with colorful 'C' icon on blue background and a Chinese name -- what is it?

Tags: applications

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy S3 for a family member (first "smart phone"). I have one myself, but this one has an app on it I can't identify (and isn't on my device), and which claims a LOT of privileges. It makes me nervous. This is what it looks like in the App manager:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: mystery app]

You can see why I would be mystified. What is this app? Do I want it? I think I don't, but might be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I traced it back to [mygyapp.com](http://www.mgyapp.com/)

[image]

But  your screenshot shows the name:

[image]

Well, based on my little search, the app in the screenshot is part of that site. That app or its mother, the site, seems to be some sort of app market. That's my educated guess. I [searched the string](http://www.mgyapp.com/search/all/page1/?keyword=%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E9%85%B7+) `应用酷` on that site and came up with this app -- which is what you've in your screenshot:

[image]

The translation differs. One translation names it "Application of cool" and the other, "Applications cool". The product page shows:

(See original [here](http://www.mgyapp.com/apps/detail-4624); [Bing translation](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=zh-CHS&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mgyapp.com%2Fapps%2Fdetail-4624%3Floc%3Dsearch%26ext%3Dresult%26ext2%3D%25E5%25BA%2594%25E7%2594%25A8%25E9%2585%25B7))

[image]

[image]

### More info:

- **App name**: `应用酷`
- **Package name**: `com.mgyapp.android`
- **Permissions:**

  ```
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_TASKS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_LOGS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_SMS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_SMS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.SEND_SMS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
  uses-permission: name='android.permission.FLASHLIGHT'
  uses-permission: name='com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT'
  uses-permission: name='com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT'
  uses-permission: name='com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS'
  ```

  <sub>(I used the answer for [Obtain package name AND common name of apps via ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664) to obtain the aforesaid permissions.)</sub>

  **Simplified permissions:**

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG:][image: IMG:][image: IMG:]

---

**Not important to read.**

---

#### How did I find all the info?

1. Fortunately, you provided a screenshot with good resolution so I separately cropped app's icon and name.
2. I extracted the name from the image using a website featuring online OCR.
3. I used the raw name into Google/Baidu search and there we go!

Of course, I did too many mistakes here and there.

Comment: The permissions are for the version 3.0.2.

Comment: I just recalled that since you've the device in your possession, it could've been a lot easier to dig all this info. Just open it and browse it into "About us" or something.