# 'Authorization Failed' toast message at startup

Tags: boot, 6.0-marshmallow, htc-one-m8

Every time I reboot my HTC One M8 Google Play Edition running 6.0 Marshmallow, there is a toast message that reads 'Authorization Failed' with no other information on what actually failed.

Any idea what is causing this so I can fix it?

Comment: Can you try a hard reboot?

Comment: What's a hard reboot as opposed to a power off/on?

Comment: You remove the battery as well

Comment: The HTC One M8 does not have a removable battery.

Comment: Install [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) to record notifications and toasts from apps. Make sure you've initialized this app and activated the required settings. Do a reboot, let the toast show up, open the said app and look into all the entries. You should be able to see the Toast and the owner app. Alternatively, have [tag:ADB] setup in PC and USB debugging enabled in device, let the toast show up and when it does, execute the command `adb shell dumpsys window` and look for the string `TOAST`  (possibly `TOAST_WINDOW`)...

Comment: ..Before the string would be name of the package causing that particular toast. If you do find the name, report it to us or use this answer to get the app's label: [Obtain package name AND common name of apps via ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664) Once you've the app name, I believe you would be able to find out what may be causing the issue. However, could it be that you already know which app causes that toast?

Comment: Maybe it's one of the HTC-sense's built-in apps like _Facebook_. Try removing your [Facebook  account from _Blinkfeed_](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m7/274490-facebook-bugs-authorize-htc-sense.html#post2929180)

Answer (score 2):

Improvising Firelord's comment, if you are using  Linux, execute in terminal

```
adb shell dumpsys window > log.txt
```

and then,

```
cat log.txt | grep 'TOAST'
```

Now, you can find the package name and app causing the problem.

Comment: Firelord didn't post an answer but a comment because Firelord, before posting an answer, tries to make sure that the answer is to-the-point and OP doesn't end up saying, "it doesn't work". Given that OP has not replied back to Firelord's any comment, it can be assumed that either Firelord's approach didn't work or OP didn't understand it clearly or didn't consider replying back  for some unbeknownst reason. In any case, further clarification is needed from OP.

Comment: Furthermore, the reason Firelord indirectly said "*look for the string*" instead of suggesting 'grep' is because there isn't any  evidence that OP uses a \*nix based system. Another thing, *your answer is nothing more than what Firelord already said*. Consider detailing your answer such as what is `dumpsys window` doing here. Also, the command can also be `adb shell dumpsys window | grep "TOAST_WINDOW"`. Even then, where is the package name? Show it as an example. Then again, it is the package name and not the app name. How do I find out what's the app name?

Comment: Also, consider linking to what ADB is or how to setup it in PC, since we don't know whether OP has used it before. It appears that you've not tested the answer before posting. If you did, show us the details. That's what increases the authenticity of  the answer   Please follow [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Rohit, could you expand your answer into what would fit the question or what the other user asked for? It appears that the other user isn't going to post a formal answer and thedude19 hasn't accepted this answer either. Besides, I just looked it now and I've difficulty following it. It seems bits and pieces. See if you can expand this into an easy, step by step understandable answer. That might even win you 50 points. :D