# Can I get an app package name as a Tasker Variable upon a package updated event?

Tags: applications, tasker

I'm trying to use Tasker to create custom notifications with AutoNotification with the Event Context of "Package Updated *". But what I really need is to know if when a package is updated, does the updated app package name get passed to a variable? I already know about the intent of Package_Added from [this other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132524/167087), but it doesn't say anything about having an intent of Package_Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always employ [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) at your service to do the hunting on your own. For example: after a successful update of an app if you immediately execute the following command and follow the section *ACTIVITY MANAGER BROADCAST STATE (dumpsys activity broadcasts)* you would come across the intent *[android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)*. You would also observe that the data in that intent contains the much sought package name.

```
adb shell dumpsys activity
```

Relevant demo output:

```
#0: BroadcastRecord{dec5090 u0 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED}
    act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.koushikdutta.backup flg=0x4000010 (has extras)
    extras: Bundle[{android.intent.extra.UID=10185, android.intent.extra.REPLACING=true, android.intent.extra.user_handle=0}
```

As for using the information in Tasker, setup your profile and tasks like this:

- Profile: Event → System → Intent Received

  - Action: `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED`
  - Scheme: `package`
  - leave the rest untouched
- Task: (Actions):

  - Variables → Variable Search Replace

    - Variable: `%intent_data`
    - Search: `package:`
    - tick One Match Only
    - tick Replace Matches
    - Replace With: leave this untouched since we want to delete the match

      The package name alone would now be available to the value of the variable `%intent_data` (a local variable). Use it wherever you want.

  In order to get the app label, you can either use Tasker's inbuilt functionality or use [`aapt`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/96277) (latter requires root access)

  - App → Test App:

    - Type: Package Name
    - Data: `%intent_data`
    - Store Result In: `%label`

      The app label can now be retrieved from the variable `%label`.

See [Accessing Intent Data](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/intents.html) for more info on intent handling in Tasker.

*Homework*: if you follow the output of *dumpsys activity* carefully you would note that the information that the app has been updated can actually be retrieved from *android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED* alone.

Related: [Get new installed app name with Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132509/96277)