# Check for install then uninstall with Tasker

Tags: tasker

I'm new to tasker, just got it today.

I want to set up a profile that looks at the apps I am installing and if it is on some block-list, uninstalls it. 
I've seen this answer (to a related question):
[Get new installed app name with Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132509/get-new-installed-app-name-with-tasker?newreg=f03d9a026aeb4b4c8e7dcbdea1406488)

But I am still not quite getting it.

Comment: Tasker or any third party app cannot know which app is getting installed. They get to know about the app only when it has been installed. All you can do with Tasker is initiate the deletion immediately after installation if the app is blacklisted.

Comment: Ok, how would I do this?