# Commands run on terminal but throw errors in shell script

Tags: adb, permissions, shell, command-line, scripts

I created a .sh script which sets app permissions on Android devices.
If I push the script on `/sdcard` and run it through `adb shell` with command `sh ./test.sh`, the following error occurs on each permission:

```
Bad argument: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Here is my Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm grant com.android.camera2 android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
pm grant com.android.camera2 android.permission.CAMERA
pm grant com.android.camera2 android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
pm grant com.android.camera2 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
pm grant com.android.camera2 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.CAMERA
pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

So every time the same command for different permissions and different apps. If I'm using these commands manually on `adb shell` it works.

I don't have root permissions and the device OS is Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there seems no reason for this, except the possible problem with [line endings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) which often happens. On *NIX operating systems (including Android), lines end with Line Feed (LF; `\n` or `0x0A`) while on DOS/Windows with Carriage Return + Line Feed (CRLF; `\r\n` or `0x0D0x0A`). On Mac, only `CR` is the end-of-line marker. So some text editors may encode wrong line breaks in shell scripts:

```
~$ cat -v /sdcard/test.sh
#!/bin/bash^M
^M
pm grant com.termux android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE^M
```

Here `^M` is the visual representation of `CR`, which can be fixed with `dos2unix`, `sed` or `tr` utility:

```
~$ dos2unix /sdcard/test.sh
~$ cat -v /sdcard/test.sh
#!/bin/bash

pm grant com.termux android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Now the problem should be resolved.