# Writing Script to add eth0 interface on S7 edge

Tags: shell

can someone take a look over this script? I want to add it in a sh file. When I connect my ethernet adapter I don't want enter all commands again. I just want to execute it from shell. Is this correct?

```
#!/bin/sh
ip link set eth0 up
sleep 1;
ip addr add 192.168.178.50/24 dev eth0
sleep 1;
ip route add default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0
sleep 1;
ndc network create 1
sleep 1;
ndc network interface add 1 eth0
sleep 1;
ndc resolver setnetdns 1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
sleep 1;
ndc network default set 1
```

When I enter the commands directly into terminal emulator ir works, when I execute the script with `#sh filename.sh` I get error.

The second problem is, my file in root folder isn't here anymore after reboot.

Comment: question can be answered by testing yourself. shebang is #!/system/bin/sh for android

Comment: @alecxs `/bin` can be a symlink: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/ff1ef9f2b10d98131ea8945c642dd8388d9b0250

Comment: it does not work as espected. when I enter the commands directly into terminal emulator ir works, when I execute the script with #sh filename.sh I get error. The second problem is, my file in root folder isn't here anymore after reboot.

Comment: Answered here: [Any changes to files in root directory (/) are gone after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/any-changes-to-files-in-root-directory-are-gone-after-reboot) and [Commands run on terminal but throw errors in shell script](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209414/218526)

Comment: Irfan Latif, thanks for your help. But If I use ethernet seldom, so its enough to copy and paste the commands over ADB Wifi. The ndc commands work, but with ifconfig you only configure your IP and netmask. The gateway works also over ndc, the command is ndc network route add <netid> eth0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0 (the last 0.0.0.0 stands for your gateway IP).