# SHELL Command works fine as a standalone command, but fails when put into a shell script?

Tags: adb, shell, scripts, bash

Android 8.1 PIXEL 2 with root access.

I have seen this asked here once before but the only solution didn't help me at all. I am going to try and make this as simple as I can for the example.

If I run the following command in terminal emulator or adb shell:

```
am force-stop com.myapp.frustrated
```

It will quit the app just fine. But when I run it in this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
am force-stop com.myapp.frustrated
```

Nothing happens. It is odd to me that I can do many other commands just fine in a script, but a handful of them do not work.

Any suggestions you have are much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that shell exists at path `/bin/sh` or use `/system/bin/sh`. Also take care of line endings in script: [Commands run on terminal but throw errors in shell script](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208064/commands-run-on-terminal-but-throw-errors-in-shell-script)

Comment: Are you running the script from within a adb shell or just from the command prompt with adb?

Answer (score -1):

Removing `#!/bin/sh` fixed my issue. Thanks

Comment: Replacing it by `/system/bin/sh` would most likely have worked as well. Background: That line specifies the binary ("interpreter") to run this script with. As there is no `/bin/sh` on Android, the specified interpreter wasn't found and thus the script not run. Could you please verify that – and then integrate these facts with your answer? When done please ping me, so I can remove my comment again.

Comment: As a side note: on recent Android versions `/bin` is a symlink to `/system/bin`.