# How to get titles of installed apps on device?

Tags: adb, windows, command-line

I connected Android device to desktop with Windows using USB. I need to get titles of installed apps. What command for Windows command line to complete the task? I used ADB for other tasks, but while I did not find solution for this task.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There's an existing question asking a bit more elaborate issue, but the approach is still the same albeit complicated since there's no way to know the app title by ADB only. Please take a look and good luck.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250521/218526).