# App acting differently on 2 different devices

Tags: settings, apk, android-tv, debug

I have a streaming app which has an internal player (not great) but it also allows us to use MX Player.
The app is installed on my Android TV and also my Nvidia shield.

On the android TV, if I chose to use the External player (MX Player) it works fine, MX player comes up and the stream plays there fine.

On the shield, when I select to play on the External player, It opens the Play Store and a message pops up on the bottom of the screen asking me to install MX Player.
However, MX player is already installed.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it makes no difference.

It is the exact same app on both devices and I can not understand why it works perfect on one but not the other.

Are there any recommended areas to check?

Comment: Did you download and install MX Player from the same source? Could you [check the package name](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/90141/44325) both on Android TV and Nvidia Shield? Otherwise, there might be a (weird?) internal check in the source code whether it runs on Android TV or not. You could probably try [checking the logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) and view the requested `Intent` when going through it, but without knowing how the app really works, it usually becomes guesswork...

Comment: Just a guess: if the app is older and the Nvidia shield uses a recent Android version the app may be not allowed to check if MX Player is installed because the app does not declare the necessary URL schemes it is allowed to check. On older Android versions like your TV this missing declaration has no effect but on your shield it blocks the app from checking if MX Player is present.