# Missing account name and app icon in account entry - NothingToSeeHere account

Tags: accounts

[image: The mysterious account]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

See that account with the Android icon and missing name? It's an account called "NothingToSeeHere". Does anybody know what could it be and how can I check it?

I turned it off and now I can't turn it on but it's still on the "Add Account" page. Although I can't click on it to show you the name, "NothingToSeeHere".

Here's the (sensitive data censored) dump from account service:

```
User UserInfo{0:XXXXXXXXXX:13}: 
Accounts: 4 
Account {name=XXXXXXX@gmail.com, type=com.facebook.auth.login} 
Account {name=Messenger, type=com.facebook.messenger} 
Account {name=XXXXXX XXXXX, type=hr.apisit.u03.kp} 
Account {name=XXXXXXXX@gmail.com, type=com.google} 

AccountId, Action_Type, timestamp, UID, TableName, Key Accounts History 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-02 03:14:40,10054,accounts,0 
1,action_account_add,2016-01-02 03:15:44,10007,accounts,1 
1,action_set_password,2016-01-02 03:15:44,10007,accounts,2 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-03 00:35:18,10007,accounts,3 
2,action_account_add,2016-01-03 03:13:50,10156,accounts,4 
3,action_account_add,2016-01-03 12:39:15,10149,accounts,5 
4,action_account_add,2016-01-03 12:39:54,10148,accounts,6 
5,action_account_add,2016-01-04 00:09:34,10132,accounts,7 
-1,action_called_account_remove,2016-01-04 00:38:45,1000,accounts,8 
1,action_account_remove,2016-01-04 00:38:45,10007,accounts,9 
-1,action_called_account_remove,2016-01-04 00:39:48,1000,accounts,10 
2,action_account_remove,2016-01-04 00:39:49,10156,accounts,11 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-04 00:41:43,0,accounts,12 
6,action_account_add,2016-01-04 00:42:23,10007,accounts,13 
6,action_set_password,2016-01-04 00:42:23,10007,accounts,14 
7,action_account_add,2016-01-04 23:11:16,10156,accounts,15 
-1,action_called_account_remove,2016-01-05 15:22:19,1000,accounts,16 
7,action_account_remove,2016-01-05 15:22:20,10156,accounts,17 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:30:12,0,accounts,18 
8,action_account_add,2016-01-05 15:30:13,10156,accounts,19 
-1,action_called_account_remove,2016-01-05 15:30:20,1000,accounts,20 
8,action_account_remove,2016-01-05 15:30:20,10156,accounts,21 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:35:37,0,accounts,22 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:35:44,0,accounts,23 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:35:51,0,accounts,24 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:35:56,0,accounts,25 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:36:36,0,accounts,26 
-1,action_called_account_add,2016-01-05 15:37:13,0,accounts,27 

Active Sessions: 6 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 8307.921, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 7982.812, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 7976.194, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 7963.836, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 7923.559, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 
Session: expectLaunch false, connected true, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 7886.837, addAccount, accountType zephyr.headlezz.net, requiredFeatures null 

RegisteredServicesCache: 12 services 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.android.sim}, ComponentInfo{com.qualcomm.simcontacts/com.qualcomm.simcontacts.SimAuthenticateService}, uid 1000 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=hr.apisit.u03.kp}, ComponentInfo{hr.apisit.u03.kp/hr.apisit.u03.kp.account.AccountAuthenticatorService}, uid 10132 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountAuthenticatorService}, uid 10007 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.lge.sync}, ComponentInfo{com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.model.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10020 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=zephyr.headlezz.net}, ComponentInfo{com.lolsummoners/com.lolsummoners.logic.sync.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10156 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.facebook.messenger}, ComponentInfo{com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.messaging.phonebookintegration.account.MessengerAuthenticatorService}, uid 10148 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.skype.contacts.sync}, ComponentInfo{com.skype.raider/com.skype.android.service.AccountService}, uid 10130 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google.android.gm.legacyimap}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.service.LegacyImapAuthenticatorService}, uid 10069 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.facebook.auth.login}, ComponentInfo{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.platform.FacebookAuthenticationService}, uid 10149 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google.android.gm.pop3}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.service.Pop3AuthenticatorService}, uid 10069 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice}, ComponentInfo{com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service/com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service.server.syncadapter.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10010 ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.android.localphone}, ComponentInfo{com.qualcomm.simcontacts/com.qualcomm.simcontacts.PhoneAuthenticateService}, uid 1000
```

- Phone: LG G3 D855 32GB
- System: Android 6.0 Marshmallow (stock 30B rooted)

Comment: There should be some crazy app that hasn't implemented it properly. Find & Remove that blacksheep, and you're done :)

Comment: Are you using Lollipop or do you have root access? Setup [tag:adb] and do `adb shell dumpsys account` and give us the result.

Comment: LG G3 with Android 6.0 recently flashed and rooted from stock ROM, almost fresh!

Comment: I'll try the dump via adb ^_^

Comment: There, uploaded the dump from terminal emulator.

Comment: Can you consider removing this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lolsummoners and see whether that entry vanishes? If not, then consider disabling https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service and then tell us the results. Use @ followed by user's name to ping them.

Comment: @Firelord yeah it was the League of Legends API x) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be safely assumed that the apps which have an entry under Settings → Accounts uses Android's [sync adapter framework](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) to sync the app data with their server. In that case, system service `account` can give you info about the apps which have registered themselves to use the said framework. Using such info, you can either disable the apps one by one or go berserk with all to pin-point the troublemaker.

## Troubleshooting instructions

<sub>(Tested on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2)</sub>

Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute:

```
adb shell dumpsys account
```

It would show info for all the user accounts, be it primary or secondary. Under `User UserInfo{0:XXXX:13}:` i.e. for primary user, after the string `RegisteredServicesCache:` find all the lines starting with `ServiceInfo:`.

In the output you provided, those lines are:

```
RegisteredServicesCache: 12 services 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.android.sim}, ComponentInfo{com.qualcomm.simcontacts/com.qualcomm.simcontacts.SimAuthenticateService}, uid 1000 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=hr.apisit.u03.kp}, ComponentInfo{hr.apisit.u03.kp/hr.apisit.u03.kp.account.AccountAuthenticatorService}, uid 10132 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountAuthenticatorService}, uid 10007 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.lge.sync}, ComponentInfo{com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.model.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10020 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=zephyr.headlezz.net}, ComponentInfo{com.lolsummoners/com.lolsummoners.logic.sync.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10156 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.facebook.messenger}, ComponentInfo{com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.messaging.phonebookintegration.account.MessengerAuthenticatorService}, uid 10148 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.skype.contacts.sync}, ComponentInfo{com.skype.raider/com.skype.android.service.AccountService}, uid 10130 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google.android.gm.legacyimap}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.service.LegacyImapAuthenticatorService}, uid 10069 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.facebook.auth.login}, ComponentInfo{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.platform.FacebookAuthenticationService}, uid 10149 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.google.android.gm.pop3}, ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.service.Pop3AuthenticatorService}, uid 10069 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice}, ComponentInfo{com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service/com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service.server.syncadapter.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10010 
ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.android.localphone}, ComponentInfo{com.qualcomm.simcontacts/com.qualcomm.simcontacts.PhoneAuthenticateService}, uid 1000
```

In each line after first line, you would see an example of this template:

```
ComponentInfo{ABC/XYZ}, uid ID
```

The ABC here is the package name of the app whose entry is listed under Settings → Accounts. ID is Android UID allotted to that package.

Now, I was able to lessen my scope to [`com.lolsummoners`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lolsummoners) as the troublemaker is because in the screenshot you provided, these apps already have an icon:

<sub>(To get app's label using its package name, use GAThrawn's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19866/96277) - works if only the app is available in Play Store; use Izzy's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/96277) - works for any installed app.)</sub>

- Facebook        - `com.facebook.katana`
- Play Services   - `com.google.android.gms`
- Messenger       - `com.facebook.orca`
- mPretinac       - `hr.apisit.u03.kp`
- Skype           - `com.skype.raider`
- Gmail POP3/IMAP - `com.google.android.gm`

The ones left were:

- `com.qualcomm.simcontacts`                 - uid: 1000  - a system app
- `com.android.contacts`                     - uid: 10020 - a system app
- `com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service`  - uid: 10010 - a system app
- `com.lolsummoners`                         - uid: 10156 - a user app

Because I based troubleshooting on the assumption that the issue would most likely be the work of a user installed app, I asked you to remove `com.lolsummoners`. As a fail-safe, I suggested disabling `com.lge.bioitplatform.sdservice.service`.

Thankfully, the first one worked out and you also learned how to troubleshoot such an issue effectively in future.

Comment: Great and instructive answer! :)

Comment: Sure, no problem.