# What is "http://www.168077.com/12078/index.html" this webpage on my Tab browser

Tags: browser, tablet, lagging

I am getting this web page,titled "smart Site" 
**http://www.168077.com/12078/index.html** on my Android Tab. Even After resetting to factory setting, it keeps popping up after some time.
After selecting any browser it redirects above link. Like This,
[image: After selecting any browser it redirects to the site titled "smartSite"]

I am afraid if it is something like any hack ware or something, I don't know.
My tab also lags after  opening this site

I am using *BSNL PENTA T-PAD 83AAQ1* purchased from *Amazon*. Android Lolipop with 1 GB RAM.
Thanks. Sorry for bad English

Comment: Does the browser launches itself on its own (or even if you have to select a browser but you didn't do anything prior to it) with that website? Or, does that website is launched in a tab of any browser when you are browsing something? See related Q&A: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/178024/96277

Comment: Maybe DNS poisoning? Does other devices on that WiFi network opens same page in browser?

Comment: No, I am using SIM Card not WIFI, and even on the hotspot, no devices show such behaviour.

Comment: After Scratching my head for so many days, I got an idea which works. I hide all unwanted packages using adb shell pm hide "packagename". I think com.adups.fota was the culprit

Comment: This is seemingly an extremely stubborn malware, that probably came  to my android device through play store.  Even if I reboot my NO-root device into "safe mode", it persists. However I was able to remove it by a factory reset, at least apparently.