# Finding out what App causes unwanted new tabs in firefox on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware, 8.0-oreo, firefox-for-android

Recently some app started opening new firefox tabs with the adress 'livemobilesearch.com'. I uninstalled the most recentently installed apps, but the problem still persists. I assume the pages get opened when I unlock my phone from standby, because sometimes after I unlock the phone the screen flashes for a second and if I open the firefox after that, a new tab with said webpage is open. I already deleted the 'cache' and 'data' of the firefox app but nothing changed. Also I tried an anti virus and malware software called "Malwarebytes Security: Virus Cleaner, Anti-Malware", but it didn't find anything. I have two ideas / questions to find out what causes this problem:

1. Does the firefox app have a logfile that tracks from where pages are openend?
2. Is there a way to see a list of receivers that are 'subscribed' to the SCREEN_ON Event?

If anyone has another idea to how to fix my problem I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've read and followed the instructions of the related articles from the comments. dumpsys activity activities shows the following:

```
* TaskRecord{3bf05cb #1075 A=com.android.chrome U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a103 mCallingUid=u0a103 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=com.android.chrome
  affinity=com.android.chrome
  intent={act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://livemobilesearch.com/?utm_campaign=dist&utm_source=foobar flg=0x14002000 pkg=com.android.chrome cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity}
  realActivity=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity

....

* Hist #0: ActivityRecord{bbeee47 u0 com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity t1075}
      packageName=com.android.chrome processName=com.android.chrome
      launchedFromUid=10103 launchedFromPackage=com.android.chrome userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{408bf79 18941:com.android.chrome/u0a103}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://livemobilesearch.com/?utm_campaign=dist&utm_source=foobar flg=0x14002000 pkg=com.android.chrome cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{3bf05cb #1075 A=com.android.chrome U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=com.android.chrome
      realActivity=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity
```

The way I understand the output is, that the tabs were opened from chrome. I've disabled chrome for now, as I can't uninstall it.

EDIT 2: 
The problem still persits. Even though I followed the steps in the similar thread in the comments, the unwanted page still gets opened. I can't uninstall Chrome since it is a system app (I have a sony xperia x compact on Android 8.0.0).

After I disabled Chrome the unwanted page is still opened. It now states in the dumpsys: "launchedFromPackage=org.mozilla.firefox". It would appear, that the solution form the comments is in my case not working.

Any advice would be much apreciated.

Comment: Hi. Can you do this? Connect the phone to PC, start saving output of logcat command into a file through `adb logcat -v long,descriptive > logcat_output.txt`, unlock the screen and wait for the browser with that URL to be launched, and when done launching, press `ctrl + c` to exit saving the logcat's output. After that, share the logcat file with us using "github paste" or pastebin website. // Logcat is a very important tool to troubleshooting issues with Android.

Comment: I've put the logcat here: https://pastebin.com/VZHXFeNW
You can search for "livemobilesearch" to find the place where the page gets opened.

Comment: Can you  give me the output of `adb shell dumpsys package > dump_pkgs.txt` or alternatively, `adb shell 'dumpsys package | grep -B1 -e 10331 
 -e 10021'`? Also, tag me with @Firelord to notify me of your comment. Thanks

Comment: @Firelord here is the "dumpsys package": https://gist.github.com/KArlkackt/5bc56b4b627bcd1772ec73d7c4d42420

Comment: Can you disable or uninstall the [Farming Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giantssoftware.fs18.google&hl=en_US) app in your device and see whether the browser is still launched with that URL automatically upon unlocking the device? It is identified by some anti-malware programs as 
 potentially malicious. See https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/f11ee8a9522d73c8af296a3eca21a7487db48923ae8bdccabef919651bc4c592?environmentId=200 for more

Comment: @Firelord After uninstalling the farming simulator, the problem went away. Thank you so much! I thought, because I paid for the app, the developer would not place malware in their product, but as it turns out I was wrong. Lesson learned. If you post an anwser I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm glad we were able to work this out. However, I cannot post an answer here because the question is still a duplicate to that question. I've, however, added my findings from this answer into my other [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/178024/96277), so that it benefits people who would be spammed, like you, in future.  If you intend to vote, which is voluntary, you may upvote it there. Thanks!