# Today, my phone out of nowhere started opening random spam/scam sites. What can I do to make it stop

Tags: malware

I have an Huawei mate 10 lite, and today it started randomly opening my browser and showing me scam sites. I have tried some anti-virus apps, but after a full scan they didn't find anything. I also looked at my apps, to see if anything suspicious app was there, but I didn't find any blank app/unknown app. The only thing I don't want to do is to factory reset my phone. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: First thing is to clear the cache of the phone and reboot

Comment: find a way to backup important apps, factory reset seems the safest solution

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177990/how-to-find-out-which-app-is-trying-to-open-spam-websites) had the answer for me.  It turned out to be the latest QR code scanner.  It said it had ads but did not say it opened them in the default browser randomly.