# Built-in Trojan?

Tags: tablet, malware, 9.0-pie, antivirus, virus

So I bought this tablet from a little-known company called iGet. The tablet was brand new and all the apps you see on the following screen came with the tablet or were installed from the Play store (Camera, Clock, FM Radio, and Sound Recorder are built-in).

[image: apps on the tablet]

The model of the tablet is Smart W103. It runs Android 9 Pie.

The problem is that ESET finds a trojan as part of the OS. Or could it be a false positive? AVG was not able to detect it.

**TrojanDropper.Agent.DHC** is the culprit in question. It's in **MtkSettings.apk** as part of settings.

[image: ESET scan]

Some other info:
When you press **Build number** in settings several times, you get developer as usual. However, pressing **Custom build version** several times reveals the **Device info** option.

[image: Custom build version]

There it's possible to get to several advanced features:

- pressing **ProductName info** several times opens **MTKLogger**
- pressing **LCM info** several times opens **EngineerMode**
- pressing **TP driver** opens **Hardware Check**

[image: Device info] [image: MTKLogger] [image: EM] [image: HC]

Also "spam" links open in Chrome randomly on their own from time to time. What's up with that? See attached screenshot for reference.

[image: spam]

Comment: Extract the APK and upload it to virustotal.com usually you will see that may be one or two will detect it as something generic but not more. Then the chance is that it is a false positive.

Comment: In order the find the spamming app, you can try the approach in the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233762/96277) or in my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/178024/96277).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to extract from system folder without rooting. However I'll certainly try that Chrome browser trick.

Comment: @IJK_Principle please use @ followed by the name of the person to whom you are trying to address with your comment. Otherwise, nobody would be notified of any of your comments. As concerns extracting APK, you don't need root access for that. Try any famous "backup" app from Play Store and it should be able to do the work for you. You can try this libre software app as a starting point. https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.smartpack.packagemanager/

Comment: @Robert this is the result https://i.imgur.com/vhbdZDN.png ,I used Package manager from F-Droid as suggested by Firelord. Seems only ESET finds something malicious. I won't worry. Thanks

Comment: @Firelord thanks for suggesting the Package manager app. I'll try your tips regarding the spam next, thanks.