# Android malware opens browser tabs with spec. URL

Tags: browser, malware

I got Android malware on my Redmi 9 smartphone which open numerous tabs on my browser with the URL `https://jaavnacsdw.com/GAS/GAS.php?c=1797742&c1=VAR`. One time, I had 133 tabs.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Did you install or update an app recently? We have an existing question to guide the user on identifying the malware app: [How to find out which app is trying to open spam websites?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177990/44325). Please take a look and have a try. Good luck!