# "Weather is running" notification

Tags: applications, notifications, 8.1-oreo

Running 8.1.0 on a Moto x4: I keep getting this notification:

> **Weather is running**
>
> Tap for more information or to stop the app.

[image: Weather is running notification]

If I tap and Force Stop the Weather app, it comes back before long.

1. How can I *really* keep the Weather app from running in the background?
2. Or, if I want it to run in the background, how can I prevent this notification from constantly appearing?

Comment: I'm getting this message, too. On a HTC 12+ I can't delete the app and deactivating it does not stop it from being executed in the background. This is why the message appears for me, too.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> [How] can I prevent this notification from constantly appearing?

If you long-press that notification you would be given the option to turn off the notifications for that app. Since it is Android Oreo, you may even get the option just to turn off that particular category of notification from Weather app. In Android 9, 10 and 11, you can also change a notification's priority status to "Other" and enable "Minimize" so that they at least become less infuriating and smaller in size, if cannot be hid completely.

---

If that doesn't work out for you, than I suggest you try [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). You can detect that notification and clear it automatically and immediately.

Setup MacroDroid and setup permission for "Notification access" and "Modify system settings" in it. Setup a macro with the following details:

**Trigger**: Device Events → Notification → Notification Received → Select your application:

- Text Content: select *Contains*
- Text to enter for match: enter the text from your notification. In your case, it can either be "Weather is running" or "Tap for more information or to stop the app".
- uncheck *Ignore ongoing notifications*
- uncheck *Prevent multiple triggers*

**Action**: Notification → Clear Notifications → Select your application → fill the details mentioned above *verbatim* for the notification received.

**Constraint**: none

The next time the notification would show up, the trigger would automatically fire up the action which would immediately clear the notification.

---

> How can I really keep the Weather app from running in the background?

You can delete the app for your user account (the default user). Know that the only way to reinstall that app again as a system app is to factory reset. **Note** that removing a system app can cause boot issues, so **proceed with caution and backups taken beforehand**. However, I suggest you try disabling it first.

Disable the app from your Settings app. This should be enough to prevent the app from executing anything. If you can't disable it or it is not having the desired effect, setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) and execute:

```
adb shell pm disable-user PACKAGE_NAME  # disables the app for the current user
adb shell pm enable PACKAGE_NAME        # enables the app for the user, if you must need it again, regardless of how the app was disabled.
```

This is akin to what you'd have done using Settings app. However, if you're still adamant on uninstalling that app, run:

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 PACKAGE_NAME
```

Replace PACAKAGE_NAME with the package name of the troublesome app. To  get help in finding it, see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277).

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote this. I used to have an identical issue with another app. Long-pressing that notification gives "Android System" as the source app and no way to disable it. Disabling the app might be the only solution AFAIK, but probably unwanted for an OEMA Weather app.

Comment: @iBug I didn't really keep my answer limited to disabling it. I have given three solutions. One for disabling the notifications, the other of using MacroDroid and the last one of disabling/deleting it.  None requires root access so they all are open for everyone to try. I see no reason why the downvote should be  based on just one of them.

Comment: I found the answer really helpful and detailed! Thanks for that. I uninstalled the app because I didn't want that the positioning system for the weather app can always track me.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBoundsException I'm glad to know that it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Moto Z3 Settings > Apps > Tap on 3 verical dots > Show System > Time & Weather > Uncheck the Time and Weather box [image: Time and Weather]