# How to disable certain system notifications?

Tags: notifications

I am getting "your wifi calling was optimised" popup repeatedly. How to disable it?
My phone is Samsung S9+ running android 9. 
Notification comes whenever the phone switches to WiFi calling.

Comment: Can you follow up the first part of my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206394/96277

Comment: Could you add more info, like the device model, Android OS version, whether you're using a 3rd-party phone/VoIP app, and possibly the carrier?

Comment: @Andrew, added to the question.

Comment: @Firelord, that solution is irrelevant because my question is about an OS notification, and the question you quoted is about app notifications.

Comment: A notification is a notification, doesn't matter if it comes from Android OS, a system app or a third party app. That solution works for any type of notification. Anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on another forum:

Settings > WiFi > Advanced.

Uncheck "Network notifications."