# How do I get rid of the many sticky notices about my hotspot with tethering?

Tags: notifications, usb-debugging, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

I'm using a smartphone as a WiFi hotspot - and connecting a PC to it with a USB cable. As I plug the cable in, I get a first notification bubble:

> **USB debugging is on**
> Tap to turn off USB debugging

I don't want to get this every time I connect!... and even if I do - at least I want to be able to swipe it away. No such luck.

Now, I turn on the hotspot. This gives me two more notifications:

> **Tethering or hotspot active**
> 0 connected devices
>
> **Tethering or hotspot active**
> Tap to set up.

then I turn on USB tethering (which I also don't understand why I can't get to default to on); that yields another notification:

> **USB tethering is on**
> Tap for more options.

So, four different notifications, none of which I can swipe away.

What can I do to:

1. Make them swipeable-away?
2. Make it so that they don't show up in the first place, or at least
3. Make it so that they disappear a short while after appearing?

Notes:

- My phone is a Xiaomi 9 SE, running MIUI 12.0.2, that's based on Android 10 QKQ1.

Comment: Those messages are shown most likely because they can affect device security. Otherwise someone who gets access to your device could activate those features, remove the notification and get back the device.

Comment: @Robert: 1. I don't view my device as being secure anyway. 2. Be that as it may - I want to make the messages go away.

Comment: I just tested [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206394/96277) on an Android 10 device, and it seems to automatically swipe those notifications your have mentioned. Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, you can change their priority status by long pressing them and selecting the cog icon, than "network status", and then tap on "Other" and enable Minimize. This way, they become less infuriating.

Comment: @Firelord: The long-press doesn't work for me, but - see clarification about the phone I have. I'll try MacroDroid later on.

Comment: @einpoklum yeah sorry, I should have led with "MacroDroid part of my answer worked" . I now tested it on Android 10 (MIUI 12) on a Poco X3. Works great.

Comment: Android 13, toggle locked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ezum.png.