# Any way to disable the "Blank is draining the battery" notifications?

Tags: notifications, battery-life

I get this little popup all the time on my phone:

[image]

I can "Ignore for now" but it just comes back a few hours later.  The thing is, I'm not running the "Amazon Alexa" app currently.  I'll go in there sometimes to check my shopping list, but it's not really something I always have running.  My phone can also use Alexa as the voice assistant, but I keep it off:

[image]

Lastly, it doesn't even appear to be true.  The phone has been on for hours, and when I get that notification the battery is at 99%.  So, I'd hardly call that "draining" the battery.

Any way to disable this notification, or all notifications of this type?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you follow the second section of my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206394/96277) concerning MacroDroid? That solution works for me in removing persistent notifications.

Comment: @Firelord I'll give that a shot!  Kinda sucks you need a third party app just to get rid of annoying system level notifications..