# How do I get rid of volume limit on android

Tags: volume

How do I get rid of volume limit on galaxy note 10 lite? I tried turning off volume limit and also by turning it on while keeping volume limit to max volume. But none helped. In both cases, I was not able to increase volume past 50%. And this is utterly irritating. Today I downloaded a youtube video on home WiFi so that I can watch it while travelling. But I wasn't able to listen to anything due to high ambient noise during traveling. With volume limit, I can still listen at home, as the noise isnt that much, but today, I realised that I simply cannot listen to anything while traveling due to high noise outside.

[Here](https://youtu.be/KOaR3dpSJUY) is the screen recorded video.

I am running Android 11 and One UI v 3.1.

Comment: Can you boot into safe mode and try raising the volume to max limit so as to rule out a third-party app interfering with your volume levels? Since when did this problem start appearing? Was your device (Android OS) recently updated?

Comment: Yes / no. In the safe mode volume limit does not work at all. We can increase the volume regardless whether the volume limit is OFF or ON with low volume limit. [Here](https://youtu.be/lkerH4OWyqw) is the video trying out volume limit in the safe mode. So, yes / no: YES: we can increase the volume to MAX, but NO: volume limit doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: This is buggy behavior from your system. In safe mode, volume limit should work when it is enabled by user and should not work only when it is disabled by user. Anyhow, Reboot into Android, and follow my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214999/96277. Most likely a third party app is interfering with your volume levels. That said, you might want to explore Developer options to see if you have any related setting that might be causing this problem.