# Which application changes sound volume

Tags: settings, audio, volume-control

I would like to do some 24h logging on Android phone in order to find out which application is constantly turning the volume of notifications down to zero.

I even don't know at which time point it is happening.

Are there any ready applications for that?

Comment: Hi. Please note that seeking app recommendations is off-topic here. If you are open to trying a non-app based solution, try my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214999/96277