# How to find/identify the app that creates a sound?

Tags: audio, logging

My Android 8.0 phone generates a sound at 8:00 AM every day. It doesn't display anything on the screen while and after the sound being played. I guess this sound is created by one of my 100+ apps on the phone. I really have no idea where the sound comes from.

Is there any log on the phone that can help me identify which app creates the sound at 8:00 AM every day? Or is there any app that can help me find the app?

Answer (score 1):

Answer tested on a OnePlus 6 running Android 9.0.

---

You can setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in your PC and try this command:

```
adb shell 'dumpsys audio  | toybox  grep -i "CallingPack" | toybox sed -e "s/$/\n/g"'
```

`audio` is dump/log that  is shown to the user using dumpsys utility. The rest of the command is just to filter out relevant information.

Example output:

```
10-15 18:14:19:273 requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10096/6373 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@a9ae24fqijaz221.github.io.musicplayer.audio_playback.AudioPlayerService@d009ddc callingPack=qijaz221.github.io.musicplayer req=1 flags=0x0 sdk=28

10-15 18:19:51:868 requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10133/3213 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@c20d259 callingPack=com.arlosoft.macrodroid req=3 flags=0x0 sdk=28

10-15 18:24:47:697 requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10019/1914 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@8f116ae callingPack=com.android.systemui req=3 flags=0x0 sdk=28
```

In the output, the bold highlighted text is the package name of the apps which had caused certain sound to be played in my device at the time noted at the beginning of each line. Here's what those apps did for me:

1. *qijaz221.github.io.musicplayer* is the media player I used to play a song.
2. *com.arlosoft.macrodroid* is an automation app I used to play a brief sound in the background without showing a notification.
3. *com.android.systemui* is for a notification with a sound.

To find out which apps correspond to those package names, follow my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277).

**Note**: if the package name corresponding to your time turns out to be `com.android.systemui`, you may have to dig deep into the dump service `media.metrics`. I couldn't make much sense of its output but your case may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled by my Samsung Android 12 phone which has started playing random screeching sounds with some regularity. There was no app in foreground, it continued even after phone reboot. The phone is unmodified and not rooted. I've enabled USB debugging in Developer options, connected USB cable, ran `adb shell` and then `logcat | grep requestAudio`. After some time log records started popping out pointing to touchvpn software - look for `callingPack` parameter:

```
11-24 20:24:47.700  1114  6172 I MediaFocusControl: requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10256/23100 AA=USAGE_MEDIA/CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC 
clientId=android.media.AudioManager@7eea05corg.chromium.content.browser.AudioFocusDelegate@89e7f65 
callingPack=com.northghost.touchvpn req=1 flags=0x0 sdk=30 11-24
```