# How to find out what application triggered the notification sound?

Tags: notifications, audio

Something is randomly triggering a notification sound on my phone, but there's no banner, and if I check under "Notifications" in the settings there's nothing there either.

Is there any other way to find out which app it was? I've tried to use `adb logcat` but there's so much info in there I'm not sure what to look for. Any suggestions?

For info this is a Samsung S9 Galaxy.

---

After checking the `adb shell 'dumpsys audio'` I found the log entries related to that ring tone:

```
01-12 13:33:02:962 new player piid:6415 uid/pid:10277/29559 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x800 tags= bundle=null
01-12 13:33:02:983 player piid:6415 new AudioAttributes:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE content=CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION flags=0x800 tags= bundle=null
01-12 13:33:02:983 player piid:6415 has OP_PLAY_AUDIO:true in uid:10277
01-12 13:33:03:007 player piid:6415 state:started uid:10277
01-12 13:33:04:955 player piid:6415 state:stopped uid:10277
01-12 13:33:05:751 releasing player piid:6415
```

However it doesn't give me the name of a specific application. Any idea if it's possible to find, from this, the name of the app? Maybe based on pid?

Comment: See if my answer helps: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217612/96277

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but there was nothing for today's date. I also tried less filtering by removing the grep command but nothing obvious came up

Comment: There is an answer on that same page which uses `adb logcat`. See if that brings something up. // When was the last time you observed this sound?

Comment: @Firelord, thanks, I found the log entries related to that annoying notification (see updated post), however I'm not sure it gives any useful information. Any ideas?

Comment: After getting the UID from the logcat, you can try the answers on [How can I find app name by UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8452/44325), e.g. `adb shell pm list packages --uid 10277` to get the app's package name.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! It turns out it was `com.uniqlo.uk2.catalogue`, the Uniqlo app. I'm going to remove it and hopefully that should be it.