# Can an app send notification sounds without a displayed notification?

Tags: notifications, settings

In connection with
[Can an app bypass notification settings in Settings > Notifications > App notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/256212/can-an-app-bypass-notification-settings-in-settings-notifications-app-notifi)
(it makes no sense to copy the body of the OP),
is there any configuration state other than the 6 listed there? (I found no others).

Can an app send notification sounds without a displayed notification?
As per the 6 options above, it seems it can't.

If it can, where is that set, and how can I find which apps can do that?

Comment: Probably helpful: [How to find/identify the app that creates a sound?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217604/44325)