# What Is "Font Server"? And is it a virus?

Tags: system-apps

I've been doing malware scans for my phone pretty often recently, along with browsing and searching up apps/ files on my internal storage. I found one called "Font Server" which has a blue guy with a smile face as the image. I searched it up and found people saying it was a virus, it says it was installed in 2008 even though I got my phone in 2018 so 10 years later. I'm timid to imediently try anything so I want to make sure if anyone know what the app is/ if it is harmful/ if I should remove it or not before I do anything. Thank you!

Comment: sounds like emoji app to me. **you** found/ or some **app** found "Font Server"? in apps/ and or in storage? If app - what's the package name of this app? Who says it's a virus (link)?

Comment: you can use ([pm](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/72942)) package manager or some [app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095) to view package names