# What is a system app "AgingFunction"?

Tags: system-apps

Was just messing around with the list of apps in my phone and found an app named "AgingFunction". No, it is not one of those apps that have that aging filter that make you look old or something. It's a system app that does not have a wrapping GUI. Felt off so looked it up online but didn't find much.

Recently heard about Samsung putting an app that throttles performance on devices for so-called device life-prolonging, but turns the throttling off during synthetic benchmarks and stress tests to make it look like device performance stays constant while it does not.

Is this a similar case and should I remove it (can't really remove but disable it using platform tools)?

Comment: Hello. Give us package name of this app. If you need help in finding that see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277). Also, which Android phone and Android version are you using?

Comment: "Samsung" has been mentioned in the question, but just to confirm, is your device also Samsung? On the other hand, I found [Tecno](https://security.tecno.com/SRC/blogdetail/30) has `com.transsion.agingfunction`. Just to confirm which device it is on because each manufacturer can customize their Android and have different system/built-in apps.

Comment: @Firelord The phone I'm using is a Infinix S5 running on android 9 pie

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes Andrew I think that's the [package name since Tecno and Infinix both are owned by Transsion , they might have common package names , btw the device I'm mentioning here is a Infinix S5

Comment: Guess I'm rather late for a reply but yeah the package name is indeed com.transsion.agingfunction and yeah .. i actually did remove / disable the app through adb and having no issues whatsoever .. tried and tested it . Even used it on a fresh os install of the factory rom that came pre-installed with .. it did not have a wrapper and as per the icon was a system app .  But still couldn't figure out what it did in the first place . My phone comes from Infinix so yeah companies like Tecno and Itel also might have the same apps since it all owned by the same parent company  .. Chinese companies ..