# What is Aging Function app in Infinix phone?

Tags: hardware, infinix

Does anyone know what is this Aging Function in my Infinix phone used for?

I was looking at my phone when I saw this Aging Function. I tried to launch it but I can't.

Do I have to remove it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact model name of your phone, the Android version that is installed and best a screen shot of "Aging Fungtion" - whatever that is.

Comment: Duplicate with possible insightful comments, but not yet answered properly: [What is a system app "AgingFunction"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247716/44325)