# List of open ports on Android

Tags: security, networking

Is there a way, on a non-rooted Android device, to see a list of what apps are listening on what port? Or even a way to see if an app is listening on a specific port?

Comment: Can you nmap from different computer?

Comment: @roxan The problem with that is I need to know specifically what app is using a port. I've written 5 apps that all listen on the same port and somewhere somehow one of them isn't closing it and I need to know which one(s).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to see which app had an open port using standard linux knowledge.

Install `terminal emulator` or do an `adb shell` and execute the following:

```
shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/net/tcp                                          
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode  
  0: 0100007F:1C23 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1001        0 2111 1 e22cc000 300 0 0 2 -1
```

The important stuff above is:

- **0100007F:1C23** listen IP-address:port in hex notation, here 127.0.0.1:7203
- **00000000:0000** remote address empty (listening)
- **1001** uid of the app

You can map the uid list to apps via
[How can I find app name by UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/how-to-know-app-name-by-uid)

Comment: Hovewer, it not list all applications. I scan my device on wifi - it has 2 open ports, but in that file there is no rows, which correspond to that ports.

Answer (score 2):

Install [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor). It will list all the open ports.

Comment: Why want the app that I allow so that it can make phone calls? Why does it want to access my gallery?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mobile data connection, you don't have to worry because you should not be able to open ports (at least I am not).

If you are connected to wi-fi, you can open ports. Then you just need a computer which is connected to same network and install nmap on it and do a port scan but first you have to find out your phones local ip (**not** by going to  i.e. whatsmyip.com). You should be able to find your ip from your settings.

To run port scan on linux you have to just type: nmap (your phones ip).

Answer (score 0):

To list TCP and UDP ports:

```
ss -lntup
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always used netstat since its available on almost all android versions

```
netstat -n
```

It will list unix and transport layer sockets and their states without reverse dns.