# Which application keeps port opened on android?

Tags: networking, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of open ports on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/list-of-open-ports-on-android)

On my nexus 7 rooted device some programs keep two ports opened (8080 and 8082). How can I determine what are those applications? Netstat from terminal can't help.

Comment: See also: [Check which IPs or web-sites an app is communicating with?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32953/check-which-ips-or-web-sites-an-app-is-communicating-with/32964#32964), [List of open ports on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/list-of-open-ports-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) app. One of the things it can do is list your network connections, show the used ports and the app that is using it.