# What are these numbers in the Data Usage and Battery Usage screen in Jellybean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, security

I went to my phone manufacturer the other day to get my phone upgraded to Jellybean 4.1.2 from ICS 4.0.4. Here's the thing, I know that upgrading doesn't take long but they said it will take an hour and they made good with that, so I'm at least worried on what they did with my phone for a full hour. Well, I forgot all about it when I noticed I have some numbers instead of app names on the battery usage screen. Worse, it appears they're using my data connection. Then I went to the data usage screen and more numbers showed. Should I be worried? I asked someone with a Jellybean phone and he said all he sees on his phone are app names. I don't want to register my card on the Play Store yet unless I'm sure my phone is safe. Is this happening on anyone else? What are those numbers?

[image: Data Usage]
<sup>Screenshot of Data Usage</sup>

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots? I know you lack the rep to integrate them with your question. If you post links to them (best into your question by [editing](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46431/edit) it), one of us will take care for that. I might have some idea what that could be, but I want to make sure I've read your question correctly :)

Comment: I added a Flickr link if that is okay. That is the data usage screen. The battery usage screen only shows the numbers "0" and "1013".

Comment: As the icons indicate, these are Android services. Strange to have so many of them turning up this way. Before you added the image, I thought somebody had played with some of the test menus (I had a similar thing once when trying a bunch of "service codes") -- but here this rather looks like PIDs (process IDs) or "user IDs" (each app has a user ID, as each runs under its own user on Android). I'd confront the service center (which did the upgrade) with this, asking them what they've done. Not sure if a factory-reset would cure that, but it would also be worth a try.

Comment: So is this normal? Or does this mean a lot of apps with no names are working in the background? A factory reset huh, I guess I'll try that. Quick question though, is there an app that will let me see what links these processes access upon using the data? Or just any app that will give me more information about these processes.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's normal that there are so many apps/processes without names. Even my case (playing with service codes) turned up just a few. Usually each app should be listed with its name. This is the first time I hear/see of a case with so many. That's why I wrote: if a factory-reset doesn't clear that up, I'd confront the service team with this -- in that case I'd say something might be wrong with the ROM they flashed.

Comment: I see, I guess I'll try to factory reset first and if that doesn't help I'll ask them what they did. Thank you very much Izzy.

Comment: You're welcome, Brian! Don't forget to keep us updated (you made at least me curious). If it got solved one way or the other, you could even answer your question yourself (I'm looking forward to that! :)

Comment: Yeah, my phone is re-branded from China(I'm not implying  anything about that) but the company that brought the phone here has lots of complaints from the customers so I'm really worried if they're doing anything funny with our phones. Again, thanks Izzy! I'll keep you updated if anything changes with this.

Comment: *if they're doing anything funny with our phones* I'd say so, after your question. Never seen anything like that. If you happen to know other customers, exchange what's happening -- and take care where you buy your next device ;) I don't know that device (you never mentioned it), but you might even consider flashing it yourself (if they don't get it fixed). While waiting, you might already want to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) (instructions usually go along).

Comment: Probably related: [How to know app name by UID](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/how-to-know-app-name-by-uid)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An unknown app called 10102 shows up in Data Usage graph](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/an-unknown-app-called-10102-shows-up-in-data-usage-graph)