# Unknown apps/processes with number only are shown in data usage

Tags: applications, data-monitoring

A mysterious app named "10102" shows up in my data usage. It bears only the standard Android app icon (the Bugdroid logo with a cube on its torso). From what the graph tells me, it has used 36 megabytes of data in the background and zero on the foreground.

I think I haven't uninstalled anything for months.

Is it malware? I haven't sideloaded anything and only authorized my laptop as a USB debugger. If it's malware, how do I remove it? I have no idea how to find its package name and 10102 isn't in the list of downloaded apps in settings.

I'm running stock & never-been-rooted Android 4.4.4 on Nexus 4.

Comment: I'll let it sit for a few days. If it stops using data, it's probably some uninstalled app. Otherwise, it's most likely a malware. Either way, I'll get back to you guys and upvote and pick an accepted answer.

Comment: I just realized that I am having this case too. In my case, it's 10120 with only background usage of 40 bytes. I also tested uninstalling an app, but it just removed the entry in "Data Usage". On the other hand, there is a "Removed apps" entry inside that page too, which I think uninstalled apps' data go into there. I'll monitor this issue for a while.

Comment: Here's my list - 10926, 10266, 2021, 2030, 12161 and there are much more in my Data Usage. I usually install and uninstall apps all the time. May be these numbers belong to them.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46431/what-are-these-numbers-in-the-data-usage-and-battery-usage-screen-in-jellybean  Seems to have been confusing a few people over the years, though there's no definitive answer.

Comment: **Day 2**, the app haven't used any more data. I'll check again tomorrow. Malware or not, I want it to disappear completely from my data usage graph. It doesn't feel right.

Comment: UIDs ranging between 10000 and 19999 are assigned randomly to installed apps (system and user). If you do a factory reset or reinstall a user app, the assigned UID will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an uninstalled app. It happened on my phone a few times.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug or something.