# Help! 25 unkown apps messing with my phone

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, malware, data-monitoring, antivirus

These apps keep showing up in my data usage screen. I have no idea what they are or where they came from. There are 25 of them by the way. All they seem to do is use up data and interfere with my phones operation. I.E. slowing it down, closing other programs, opening Google play asking me to download one thing or another, pretty sure they've ended a couple of my calls. Though I can't prove it. NO anti-malware picks them up.

If it is an app I've installed causing the problem how do I figure out which one (short of installing them one at a time)? Is there anyway to get rid of them (short of formatting phone again or performing a factory reset)?

I'm not a pro so I need it simply explained. Not dumb either. My phone is not rooted and I'd rather not if I don't have to. It looks like a pain and I'm not great with Linux systems. My phone it a ZTE Rapido LTE model Z932L, Android version 4.1.2. Any help would be great.

Edit: I don't think the question that is similar to mine answers my question. Tho the are very similar. I did not have my phone updated or messed with by the company I bought it from. Its a straight talk phone. To my knowledge there isn't anywhere I could take it. I have factory reset my phone twice and the problem continues. It could very well be something I did (infact that's the most likely conclusion). If it is I need to know what so I don't do it again lol. Also added screen shot of "removed apps," and two more have popped up since I posted this question. I have not uninstalled anything.

[image: removed apps] [image: screen shot of some of the 25 unknown apps]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Another similar question: **[An unknown app called 10102 shows up in Data Usage graph](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/an-unknown-app-called-10102-shows-up-in-data-usage-graph)**

Comment: I think these are just the uninstalled apps that have used data.

Comment: @GokulNC though that wouldn't explain the slowing-down and closing of other apps. Still, that might be a different unrelated thing; uninstalled apps make sense with those screenshots. // Anthony: Did you uninstall a bunch of apps lately? Have you tried restarting your device and see if those "number candidates" still turn up?

Comment: First off let me say thank you for the help. I really appreciate it. @Izzy When I first noticed them ( the numbers) I had not uninstalled anything. Since then I have uninstalled 4 or 5 apps such as 360 secerety and battery doctor. Yes I have restarted my phone and they remain. Wish it that.

Comment: @GokuINC I have my doubts as to them being uninstalled apps for two reason one being the number of them and two the is a section called removed app that shows the data they used before being uninstalled. I will replace one of the screen shots to show it. Could they still be apart of an app I uninstalled?

Comment: @Anthony the "number" would be the "UID" of the app, which no longer can be resolved to an app name with the app removed (so this makes sense). It also could be a native system process (not being an app), though that might rather be bundled into "Android OS". Also note the icon being the same as for these two, which again indicates it might be one of these two. What irritates me is they don't have an amount of data associated, but are marked "restricted" instead. Why show something in data usage that used no data?

Comment: @Izzy That's because I restricted them. Because like most people I've limited data. They range, currently, anything from a few KB to MB. After just a day or so of the showing up. Restricting them causes less issues with my phone. I've tryed letting them run on my home network, in hopes that if they they where apart of the OS in some way, maybe an update or some other system process, but my phone becomes almost useless. If it would help I can undo a few and show what data they have used.

Comment: Have you checked with [How to know app name by UID](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8452/16575) already? Maybe that gives a clue.

Comment: @Izzy I'm trying to use the emulator. However I don't know which command proment to use. And the ones in the article I've tried so far either they don't do anything, cannot be found, or I don't understand what it means

Comment: @Izzy this is the only thing that shows up after using ps l grep command line.                 u0_a100@android:/ $ ps l grep 10402
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAMEu0_a100@android:/ $

Comment: You've picked the wrong answer (see its 2nd comment). Check the answers from Firelord and Lie Ryan.

Comment: @Izzy I don't understand what there talking about.

Comment: Firelord's answer will be the easiest approach then. See our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) to get started with ADB, then follow the steps pointed out in the answer.