# How to determine exact package/application which cause undetected traffic consumption (only UID are known)

Tags: malware, data-monitoring

## The situation

Some time ago I am started to locate data traffic leakage by the some packages, which listed in traffic listings as a numeric UID (five digits long). In both selection - by the cellular data and wifi.
Device is unrooted, and can not be rooted: Sharp R2 Compact

I ask'd on web forum (4pda), about this situation, and I am was instructed to try to inspect Package Manager via ADB, but as I expects - nothing is located there with investigated UID numbers. For example, the larger consumer (about a half of gigabyte) is UID=10366 and it was in april.

```
Android/sdk/platform-tools% adb shell "cmd package list packages -U | grep 10366"
Android/sdk/platform-tools%
```

[image: uid10366]

These days some different UID numbers is still present in traffic consuming lists.

[image: uid10257]

## Questions:

Is there a way to catch which package cause "unnamed" traffic consume on unrootable phone?

Is this a malware activity or an ordinary system activity may cause the same (traffic leak tie to unnamed UID instead to exactly package/application)?

May be somwhere exist a guide to learn more how traffic is counted in system provided listings?

As a PS:
I am Android developer and can write couple lines of code to run, but I needs to be pointed to where I'll should to start from

Comment: Based on [previous questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86884/44325), these numbers usually are a remnant of uninstalled apps. Do new numbers still appear without uninstalling anything?

Comment: @Andrew T. I don't think so. First: on a first screen on the bottom present a isolated item named "Удалённые приложения" (uninstalled applications in english). Second: I am do not have equal counts on install/deinstall applications as number of UID's in traffic consuming lists. Btw, thanks for the link on previous discussion.

Comment: @Andrew T. And yes. New numbers appears without deinstalling any applications.

Comment: If you are sure that the app is not uninstalled, my answer to [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526) may help.

Comment: @Irfan Latif, seems your variants is irrelevant. First - phone is unrootable. Second - on-topic records (with UID only as a consumer) goes aside from NetGuard (on my second screenshot this tool presented by the two icons in notification bar). NetGuard send notify on every new install - this is okay. But no notifications come when some activity by the undetectable UID occurred in the system. This may be due to I am some misconfigured in the NetGuard tool.