# Are these apps with package name and random numbers malware?

Tags: applications, security, malware, data-monitoring

Did a factory reset on my phone late last month and noticed a strange app/process in data usage the last few days titled "com.sec.mimage.uid.retouching:10076", low filesize but enough to weird me out. Did another factory reset and had this come up

[image: Image showing "com.microsoft.office:10029"]

which seems to have similar if not the same data usage size. Potential malware or normal?

Comment: Look for the details on the app using my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277). As I see it, the package name corresponds to something that would come from Microsoft, but MS office's package name is different from this one when one sees its page in Play Store. Try my answer and provide to us whatever information you manage to get.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Unknown apps/processes with number only are shown in data usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86884/44325)