Unknown Package (uid-253)
Unknown Package (uid-253) Uploading Data While Charging - What Should I Do?
Hi everyone,
I noticed something unusual on my Android phone recently. A package named "Unknown (uid-253)" was detected by my data manager app, and it seems to be uploading a large amount of data whenever my phone is plugged into the charger and connected to WiFi.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Should I be concerned about this unknown package, and what steps can I take to investigate and stop this data upload?
Thanks in advance for your help!

App/package name would help. See: How can I find app name by UID?

Possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86884/2241 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46431/2241
