# Where are UID for each application stored?

Tags: applications, system

When installing an application, Android gives it an unique UID, which file(s) is used to keep track of used UIDs and to whom they belong? I want to forcibly change application UID to ensure they are the same on different device.

I've already checked with `/data/system/packages.xml`. But while that contains application permissions by package name, didn't see any UID there.

If it depends on Android version, for each versions superior or equal to 4.4.4 and source to documentation to figure it out myself for future versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already missed the correct answer.
The UIDs are stored right in `/data/system/packages.xml`, although an easier-to-interpret version with less information is available at `packages.list`.
Here's an example line of what's inside (scroll to the right)

```
<package name="jackpal.androidterm" codePath="/data/app/jackpal.androidterm-1" nativeLibraryPath="/data/app/jackpal.androidterm-1/lib" primaryCpuAbi="armeabi" flags="572996" ft="1592b6fa088" it="153d4948841" ut="158ed133c1f" version="71" userId="10001">
```

You see, there's a `userId` XML Attribute. This is exactly the UID you are asking for.
Furthermore, `userId` may be replaced by `sharedUserId` if an app shares its UID with another. Like (also scroll to right)

```
<package name="com.android.providers.telephony" codePath="/system/app/TelephonyProvider" nativeLibraryPath="/system/app/TelephonyProvider/lib" primaryCpuAbi="arm64-v8a" flags="540165" ft="159d34468e8" it="4ba52c60" ut="159d34468e8" version="1" sharedUserId="1001">
```

Of course you don't want to go through that terribly long `packages.xml`, so you might want to take a look at `packages.list`, like

```
jackpal.androidterm 10001 0 /data/data/jackpal.androidterm default 3003,1028,1015
```

Very straight, isn't it? The 2nd field delimited with space is exactly the UID and it's the same as the one in `packages.xml`.
**Do not modify `packages.list`.** All unmatching records in `packages.list` will be corrected from `packages.xml`.

Also, it's possible to change UID of an installed app *if* it does not have a shared UID. Simply edit **`packages.xml`** and reboot, then the new UID will have effect immediately. **Old data will be erased for the changed app.** If you want to keep data, apply `chown` recursively on the app's data directory in `/data/data`. If an app's old data gets erased by mismatching UID, related information will show up at `/data/system/uiderrors.txt`. Like this:

```
1970/01/01 00:00: Package jackpal.androidterm uid has changed from 0 to 10001, old data erased.
```

**Tested on Android from 4 through 5.** I guess this is applicable from Gingerbread to Nougat.

Comment: thanks i had not scanned through all data, surely the first part is permissions then UIDs.

Comment: Does this still work on Android 10? Can you pleas explain more how to avoid lossing the data? Thank You.

Comment: @Sruly *'chown -Rhv 10001.10001 /data/user\*/0/jackpal.androidterm'*

Comment: @alecxs It doesn't seem to change the apps UID it only changes the files owner and group. I'm looking for a way to change the apps UID to make it the same as the UID for this app on a different device.

Comment: @Sruly chown recursively is *"how to avoid losing the data"* (after editing *packages.xml* from this answer)