# Unknown apps/processes with number only are shown in the battery screen

Tags: applications, battery-history

There is a mysterious app, `99070` that is consuming power on my Nexus 5X. Any idea how I determine what it is?

There is no option to stop or uninstall it. My phone is a Nexus 5X running stock Android 6.0.

[image: App 99070]
[image: No additional details]

Comment: Have you uninstalled any app recently (today preferably)? It looks like an app which was used recently and uninstalled later as it shows a random number instead of app's actual name.

Comment: Related: [Why is a suspicious program draining my battery with GPS usage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/130200)

Comment: I have uninstalled some apps within the last week, but certainly not within the last 2 days. Why would that app still be running? Will a force reboot of the phone work?

Comment: @Izzy Using app manager I can see such apps as, for example, com.android.wallpapercropper (which is certainly system app), so I'd suppose the "mysterious app" can also be seen there. Or you think it's another, more system-ish sort of apps?

Comment: @nicael I'm not talking about system *apps* – but about system *processes.* You usually see them only using `ps` with a terminal/`adb shell`. E.g. on one of my devices, this shows "514" for "kswapd0", which definitely is no app (but a daemon ;)

Comment: Seems to Nexus specific http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-6p/607727-unknown-items-battery-usage-screen.html

Comment: Are you rooted?  From a root shell try running `ps aux | grep 99070` (or whatever the ID is at the time).  Could even try `find / -name *99070*` or `grep -r 99070 /`.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly right answer:

#### It's a sandboxed process from a *removed* app.

For such a number over 99000, it is the Unix UID for an **isolated sandbox process** (`u0_i70`).

In Android's UID system, called "AID". Android allocated 1000 special UIDs for isolated sanbox processes, 99000-99999. Some apps use that for security reasons, like Chrome (Incognito mode).

Comment: This answer may sound weird but that's what an experienced Android developer would give. I'm not a dev, though.

Answer (score -2):

I use OS Monitor from the Play Store to see what's going on: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en .

Here's the Help Page that pops up from the APP. http://www.osmonitor.mobi/maunal/index.html

You can view Processes and kill them or see where they connect to (with a Google Maps view of the IP Address - really nice).

Answer (score -5):

I suggest contacting Google right away and have them identify the app. Have them tell you what it's called, what does, why it's on the phone, and if there is any real need for it. If not, get Google to remove it.

Comment: I am pretty sure Google does not have people on call for app identification, much less to somehow remote into your phone and remove it for you regardless of what it is or how it got there.

Answer (score -7):

You can open the app list from the boot menu & then find the app & then uninstall it... maybe it is an unidentified process in your phone...

Comment: What boot menu? If you refer to the normal app list in *Settings › Apps*, that won't show something like that which only identifies itself by a number.