# Data usage, random number apps

Tags: applications, mobile-data

[What are these numbers in the Data Usage and Battery Usage screen in Jellybean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46431/what-are-these-numbers-in-the-data-usage-and-battery-usage-screen-in-jellybean)

I'm having a issue with apps turning up that use data in the background. I have no idea what the are or where they came from. I have factory reset my phone several times. The phone is a ZTE from straight talk. The link above shows what the apps look like only my numbers are 12437, 12984, 19154. Before I reset my phone there where a lot more of them. About 15. Is there anyway to get rid of them? Are they harmful to my phone? The phone is not rooted. And since the last reset u have uninstalled nothing. Can anyone help? Edit They also seem to be heating up and slowing down my phone due to the fact that so many are running in the back round

Edit the numbers continue to grow.
Edit in now have about 15 is there anything I can do can anyone help or am I just screwed?

Comment: Probably related: [How to know app name by UID](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/how-to-know-app-name-by-uid)

Comment: I'm not even sure what that is

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131553/mysterious-app-in-battery-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An unknown app called 10102 shows up in Data Usage graph](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/an-unknown-app-called-10102-shows-up-in-data-usage-graph)