# What is 10263 process

Tags: services

Here is the screen shot

[image: A]

I've checked the battery usage apps so that to save my battery level , I've seen a strange process 10263. I want to know what's is use

Comment: These are often applications that have been uninstalled... Particularly those starting with "10" for some odd reason. Did you recently uninstall anything?

Comment: I have recently uninstalled svt from my phone

Answer (score 0):

As I have answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179563/205764), it's the UID of a **removed** app. You can safely ignore it as it will disappear sooner or later.