# Unidentified app using excessive battery

Tags: battery-life, nexus-7

I have a battery drain issue with a stock Nexus-7 (2013), Android 6.0.1, up to date with monthly patches. The battery is losing 15-20% overnight. Turning WiFi off overnight doesn't reduce it, or not much. The top consumer is just called "10017".

Some background - A recent version of Sygic Navigation was showing high battery usage even when I didn't use the app. I couldn't keep it from running. After exiting it, or after force-stopping it, I would shortly find it running again. I deleted the app but kept its user folder. Maybe related?

I keep Google Account Manager and Google Play Store disabled when I'm not actively using them. This is not new; I've done it since shortly after the tablet was new.

I installed the August patches a few days ago; the tablet was rebooted by that process. The battery issue predates that update.

[image]

**How can I find out what it (10017) is?**

Comment: I had already uninstalled Sygic knowing that it *had been* a culprit, but it is not the current one (10017). Device is not rooted and I haven't installed, setup, etc, ADB. Currently backtracking through my (own) log looking for other updates that might be responsible. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `Settings > Storage & USB > Explore` to see if you can find/delete anything left by Sygic Navigation.

You can also try rebooting the tablet into safe mode by pressing and holding the power button until the dialog box with Power off appears. Then, press and hold the on-screen "Power off" button until it prompts you about rebooting into Safe mode. See if your battery is okay in safe mode (test it for about a day). Note that in safe mode, you can only use the core apps that the tablet came with and no third party apps. To exit safe mode, just turn off and turn back on the tablet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try dialing `*#*#4636#*#*`, it should give usage statistics that can be sorted by usage time, last time used, and app name. You will get an output as shown:

[image]

Sort by *App name*. If it shows Sygic or any other app which shows abnormal usage, then possibly the UID belongs to that app. Next steps:

- Uninstall that app and see if the situation improves
- Determining PID/UID if the above didn't help (assuming PID is the number 10017) - is easy if your device is rooted as described on [How can I find app name by UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8452/131553). Even if your device is not rooted, see [Firelord's solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122757/131553) which works for non-rooted devices

That should help you nail the culprit.

Comment: Alas, it's not a phone - no dialler.

Answer (score 1):

Backing out recently installed apps, "10017" went away when I un-installed Talkatone. I repeated the install and un-install with the same result (other than the "battery-burner" having a different numeric ID).

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky and yet simple

1. Any apps you just uninstalled will list up with UID as your phone doesn't save anything from the app once you use a cleaner app to clean up files after the uninstallation process.
2. If you still doubt it, go to Safe mode, dial up `*#*#4636#*#*`, and sort by time. This will give you a vague idea of which app it is exactly. If you still can't find out, look for a similar number as that is different based on the device. If you find something unusual like installed on Jan 1, 1970, then that's part of your phone OS. Don't tamper with it anymore. Keep calm and understand that your battery life is reducing as the device is old now like 3+ years.