# Reason of existence of An App named "-5"

Tags: battery-life, bugs, android-10, google-photos, battery-history

I was trying to look at the battery usage of different apps and saw this weird app named "-5" on inspection it takes me to google photos which is weird since why will google photos use its name as "-5". I can't find any reasoning for this and want others to shed some light on this topic. I have also reported this weird behavior to google as well.

[image]

Comment: Find out which is that app, using method [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8452/131553)

Comment: What beeshyams want's to say with the link is that "-5" may be not the app name but the Linux User ID (UID) that belongs (or had belong) to the app.

Comment: @rameshgupta1368 have recently uninstalled any app, just before this screen shot? Also, based on the icon seen on screenshot maybe its a system app.

Comment: @RahulGopi I'd agree the icon pointed to a system app if the userid wasn't prefixed with a "-". It's rather the "default icon" as the real one went away with the app being deinstalled. System apps which do not reveal their package names rather show up with "positive numbers", as they are still there. But yes, good point I fully agree with: most likely an app recently uninstalled, hence the negative prefix ("that used to be X but it no longer exists").

Answer (score 1):

I did a search in Play Store for "-5" with no results, also on YEE ole great god Google.  Not much returned.

I would start with your phone service provider.  They are suppose to give you a level of device support.  I've personally stumped the US Cellular chumps before.  Give it a try.  They do keep a knowledge base of customer calls. Who knows, you might be lucky.  Else download "HouseCall" from the Play Store, it is a TrendMicro manual scan for nasty things.  It is very powerful.  Free, only runs's when you run it.  TrendMicro has a variety of very good pay products for Android and web safe stuff.   Good luck.

Comment: "-5" is unlikely to be the app name. It's more likely an app that was recently removed, so the stats can only show its "Linux user id" (prefixed with a "-" to show it no longer exists) and a default icon.

Comment: @Izzy Having 5 as a UID, even for a system app seems unlikely. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#39

Comment: @Firelord indeed, that made me wonder too (I'd expect at least 4 digits). Oh, thanks for the link! That explains one such thing I had 9 years ago. Now I finally know what 1010 stands for :D

Answer (score 1):

It's for Wireless hotspot. Other users have reported same. read more about [here](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/57717/solved-battery-draining-fast-with-5-app)

Comment: This should be accepted answer